# Implementing a synchronized data structure in C

Tags: c, linux

Hello I built a hash table in C. I have unit tested it enough to be confident it works. The thing is that the data structure will be dynamicly linked to code that I did not write and may be using threads. So I need to synchronize it so it'll work correctly for theoretically any number of threads concurrently modifying/ reading it. After studying the pthread mutex API I did the following

Declared a static global variable:

```
static pthread_mutex_t lock;
```

On HashTable_init (which is always called before the hash table is used) I init it:

```
pthread_mutex_init(&lock,NULL);
```

On each function that reads/writes the structure I put an lock at start:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
```

and unlock at the end:

```
pthread_muter_unlock(&lock);
```

Is that enough to make an data structure synchronized? ( as at the moment my program hangs ).

Thank you

Comment: Are your mutexes recursive?  Perhaps you have a deadlock because you are trying to lock twice

Comment: Make sure you also unlock the mutex before you return at error paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be not enough. With locking each and every method, you ensure that the internal structure of your container is consistent at any point; but some uses of the container might require more than that.

Consider the following rather simple case: in one thread, you found an item by certain key and start editing it. When find() completes, it releases the lock and then returns a reference to an item. Meanwhile the lock can be acquired and another thread might for example delete this item, quite unexpectedly for the first thread.

Designing and developing a good and safe concurrent container is not an easy thing. I would recommend you instead look for ready-to-use solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Seems ok, as long as you make sure the init is called only once by the first thread and before the other threads start accessing the mutex.